# Plotly Sankey: why are nodes misplaced?

Tags: python, plotly

***(Plotly 4.10.0, Python 3.8.0, Ubuntu 20.04)***

I am working with Plotly Sankeys, but automatic placement looks quite buggy (alas I cannot place the nodes manually).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

sources = [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2]
targets = [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6]
values  = [45, 30, 15, 30, 20, 10]
labels = ['Node 0', 'Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 3', 'Node 4', 'Node 5', 'Node 6']

link = dict(source=sources, target=targets, value=values)
node = dict(label=labels)
data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node)
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show(renderer="svg", width=1000, height=500)
```

produces

[image: wrong placement]

**Why is Node 3 misplaced, and is not together with Node 4?**
Nodes are not placed according to sorted value, otherwise **Node 3** should be **below Node 6**.

Just changing from 15 to 16 the weight of **Node1->3** the placement is correct:

```
values  = [46, 30, 16, 30, 20, 10]
```

produces:

[image: correct placement]

Am I missing something here?

**-----------------------------------------**

**EDIT: Is node_pad the culprit?**

The original

```
values  = [45, 30, 15, 30, 20, 10]
...
data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node)
```

returns a faulty placement.

`data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node, node_pad=9)` solves the problem.

With `data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node, node_pad=10)` it manifests again.

It looks like a bug in calculations. I will open an issue.

Comment: What version of Plotly are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. The latest 4.10.0.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this issue, so my guess is that the newest update to `Plotly v4.10.0` may have fixed this bug.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

sources = [0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2] #indices correspond to labels
targets = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6] 
values  = [45, 30, 15, 30, 20, 10]
labels = ['Node 0', 'Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 3', 'Node 4', 'Node 5', 'Node 6']

link = dict(source=sources, target=targets, value=values)
node = dict(label=labels)
data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node)
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
# fig.show(renderer="svg", width=1000, height=500)
```

[image]

If I drastically alter some of the values, as you said, we shouldn't expect the node placement to change. `values  = [20, 30, 25, 30, 20, 10]` does not change the placement of the nodes for me:

[image]

Comment: thank you for testing. I installed the latest Dash 1.16.0 and Plotly 4.10.0 (Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8) and I SEE the issue. My mistake not to write about the versions. I will wait a little bit, to see if somebody else has an hint about it.